# repeat call of javascript function is creating conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the following JS function to have hover tooltip effect. The function works excellent. Problem happens after loading certain area with ajax. I need to call this function to work on the data collected through ajax (Jquery). That is OK as well. Problem is while I close the area called through ajax, I see unexpected behavior at the base page. The previous tooltip effects now show bubble within self (image is given below).
Any idea how to prevent this conflict?

[image: java script function causing conflict]

```
function tooltip(){
    $('.master_tooltip').hover(function(){
        // Hover over code
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
        .text(title)
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
            // Hover out code
            $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
            $('.tooltip').remove();
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
            var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
            var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
            $('.tooltip')
            .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
    });
}
```

Comment: A fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ would be nice. I'd like to see all relevant code

Comment: I'm guessing you're calling the function twice, once more after the ajax content has loaded ?

Comment: @adeneo You are right. I am calling it twice or even more. Because, otherwise data received through ajax call does not get effected by this toltip function.

Comment: There's a solution for that, it's called event delegation, and I've outlined it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call that function ***only once***, otherwise the event handlers will be bound multiple times for the already existing elements.

What you need to do is rewrite it so it delegates the mouse events and works with dynamically inserted elements, like this

```
function tooltip(){
    $(document).on({
        mouseenter : function() {
            var title = $(this).attr('title');
            $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
            $('<p class="tooltip"></p>').text(title)
                                        .appendTo('body')
                                        .fadeIn('slow');
        },
        mouseleave : function() {
            $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
            $('.tooltip').remove();
        },
        mouseover : function(e) {
            var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
            var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
            $('.tooltip').css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
        }
    }, '.master_tooltip');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but with this one I am getting errors. My firebug console shows the following error- `ReferenceError:e is not defined
error source line:
 
var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates`  What I did is, just like before I called the tooltip function within Jquery `$(function(){})`. Any Idea, where I messed up?

Comment: Oh, just forgot to add the event argument, fixed now

Comment: Owaooo.. Its working now, just in the way it was expected. Thanks a lot. :)